# How to use multiple returned value from a python function in a robot file?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have written a python function for fetching database credentials for different environments

```py
def database_creds(env):
    if env == 'staging' or env == 'qa':
        hostname = 'host1'
        username = 'user1'
        password = 'pass11'
        database = 'TestDb'
    elif env == 'production':
        hostname = 'host2'
        username = 'user2'
        password = 'pass22'
        database = 'ProdDb'
    return hostname, username, password, database
```

My doubt is how we can use each returned values in robot file?

If we are returning only one value from a python function

```
def getApiFullUrl(env):
    if env== 'production':
        url = 'production url'
    else:
        url = 'other environment url'
    return url
```

we can use like this in robot file:

```
${url}  ${getApiFullUrl('${env}')}
```

Comment: `${result1}    ${result2}    =    ${database_creds('${env}')?`

Comment: Your indentation for `database_creds()` is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Either assign them to the same number of variables (that's "automatic unpacking"):

```
${hostname}   ${username}   ${password}   ${database}     database_creds    production
```

, or assign it to a single variable and treat it as a list:

```
${data}     database_creds    qa
Log    This is the hostname - ${data}[0], and this the database - ${data}[3]
```

Comment: The output of ${data} [0] is ('TestDb', 'user1', 'pass11', 'host1')[0]. I think it is not considering it as a list.   I need the output as database='TestDb', user='user1', password='pass11', host='host1'....How will I get the output like that

Comment: There is no space between `${data}` and `[0]` - it must be `${data}[0]`, which translates to "get the value of the 1st element in the list `data`"

Comment: "I need the output as database='TestDb', user='user1', password='pass11', host='host1'" -> `Log    database= '${data}[3]', user= '${data}[1]', password='${data}[2]', host='${data}[0]'`, if it's only for output. Between "Log" and "database" there are at least 2 white spaces (preferably - 4).

Comment: I'm sorry I accidentally put that space in the comment.

Comment: Even if we are giving ${data}[0] or ${data}[1] or ${data}[2] or ${data}[3] i am getting the output as ('TestDb', 'user1', 'pass11', 'host1')[0] or ('TestDb', 'user1', 'pass11', 'host1')[1] or ('TestDb', 'user1', 'pass11', 'host1')[2] or ('TestDb', 'user1', 'pass11', 'host1')[3]

Comment: And I'm always getting the tuple/list member - if I use it like this `${data}[0]`, or like this - `${data[0]}`. Are you sure you are not calling the function in this form - `${getApiFullUrl('${env}')}`, which is not correct RF syntax?

Comment: I am passing the env through command, that's why given like ${getApiFullUrl('${env}')}.